# Apply macro on all worksheets except specified sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have developed a excel workbook which contains macros that will copy data from a Data Summary worksheet to duplicate templates (a template is created for each data row) and then it formats each sheet by a set criteria. I have this working (see code for the formatting below) however this ends up applying the formatting to all worksheets and I don't want this applied to the first two main sheets (the original template and the data summary). Does anyone know how I can amend the code so the formatting starts at the 3rd sheet (Sheet3) along?

Below is the code I am using (I've removed the part of the code with the actual formatting steps as there is alot of them and they aren't relevant to the issue so don't want to waste peoples time - happy to send if that would help though):

```
Sub FormatData1() 
     Dim xSh As Worksheet 
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
     For Each xSh In Worksheets 
         xSh.Select
         Call FormatData2 
     Next 
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FormatData2()

' REFORMATTING ELEMENTS ARE FOUND HERE (E.G. CUTTING AND PASTING OF DATA TO SPECIFIED FIELDS)

End Sub
```

---

Any thoughts or ideas to push me in the right direction?

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check a sheet's name before selecting and applying the formatting. Use an `If..Then`. To check if the sheet should not be formatted. The `AND` is added in case there are several sheets that must not be formatted. Change your code like below:

```
Sub FormatData1()
     Dim xSh As Worksheet
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     For Each xSh In Worksheets
        If xSh.Name <> "Sheet2" And xSh.Name <> "Sheet3" And xSh.Name <> "Sheet5" Then
            xSh.Select
            xSh.Cells(1, 1).Value = xSh.Name
            Call FormatData2
         End If
     Next
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```